# Store data to different Object but overwritten

Tags: java, arrays, nested

I have a problem and I totally have no idea on this, so I make a similar coding and post my question here hope u guys can help me. This is my MAIN CLASS:

```
package test;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    newclass [] NC;
    NC = new newclass[2];
    Object[][] array = new Object[5][5];
    int x=5, y=5;
    for (int i=0 ; i<2 ; i++){
        NC[i]= new newclass(array, x, y);
    }

    //solve roomHC
    for (int i=0 ; i<2 ; i++){
        NC[i].storedata();
    }

    //display solution
    for (int i=0 ; i<2 ; i++){
        System.out.print("\n");
        NC[i].display();
        System.out.print("========================");
    }
}
}
```

this is my NEW CLASS:

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class newclass {

private Object[][] array;
private int x, y;
List<Integer> slot = new ArrayList<>();

public newclass(Object[][]array, int x, int y){
    this.array = array;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public void storedata(){
    int i=0;
    while( i < 2 ){
        int a,b;
        a=(int) Math.floor(Math.random()*(x));
        b=(int) Math.floor(Math.random()*(y));
        if(NC[a][b]==null){
            slot.add(0);
            NC[a][b] = slot;
            slot = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        else{
            List templist = (List)NC[a][y];
            templist.add(0);
        }
        i++;
        }
}

public void display(){
    for(int i=0; i<x ;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<y ;j++){
            List templist = (List)array[i][j];
            if(templist==null){
                System.out.print("");
            }
            else{
             for (int k = 0; k < templist.size(); k++) {
                System.out.print(templist.get(k));
                }
            }
            System.out.print(",");    
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}

}
```

My problem is on the second loop in the main class overwrite the "0|" again in the array NC

Comment: How can you ever expect a consistent result when you use `Math.random()` to set a and b? Also `slot = new ArrayList<>();` means you are reinitializing the list each iteration of your loop so it will never hold any values.

Comment: I have edited my question, you can recheck it again..

Comment: I think now that you removed Math.random(), you will have the same results in both object no matter what. It will just put zero in the second column of both objects. It's really not clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: no, u not understand the code, there is a while loop there, so second loop the "0" will write in next column as i show my expected outcome above..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the same array of objects to both instances of `newclass`. So when you change it in one of them, the changes are made to the same array that is pointed to inside the other.

When you pass an array or an object to a method, you are passing its **reference**, not a new copy of it.

If you want each `newclass` instance to have a separate, private, not accessible from the outside, array of objects, you have to use `new` inside the constructor. For example:

```
public newclass(int x, int y){
    this.NC = new Object[x][y];
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    newclass [] NC;
    NC = new newclass[2];

    int x=5, y=5;
    for (int i=0 ; i<2 ; i++){
        NC[i]= new newclass(x,y);
    }

    //solve roomHC
    for (int i=0 ; i<2 ; i++){
        NC[i].storedata();
    }

    //display solution
    for (int i=0 ; i<2 ; i++){
        System.out.print("\n");
        NC[i].display();
        System.out.print("========================");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i not very understand ur explain... but in the main class i have declared the size of array NC [5][5]

Comment: You shouldn't just add my method to your code, you should also use the constructor I gave instead of the constructor that accepts an array. You should not create the array in the main class.

Comment: I'm still confuse, that's mean i have to remove array NC in main class, if it's removed so in the constructor should't have NC to pass anymore.

Comment: No, not NC in main class. `array` in main class. You are using the same `array`, so they are writing on the same place.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, now i have edited the code again u recheck please.

Comment: if i remove array in main class wat should i pass in the constructor ??

Comment: OK, I see that you are passing the width and height already, so I changed my suggestion and also added the way main should be written.

Comment: woo..... finally i understand, thanks for your patient man, u really helped me thanks =D